# Open password protected pdf in Word using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a macro that opens a PDF in Word but the PDF is password protected. I also have VBA code to enter the password in the dialog box that pops up but the code stops before the code to enter the password. If I enter the password manually it continues but I would like the code to entered automatically using the code I have.

```
    Option Explicit

    #If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As LongPtr
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As Long
   #Else
    Public Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Public Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
    Public Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
#End If
Public Const SW_HIDE As Long = 0
Public Const SW_SHOWNORMAL As Long = 1
Public Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED As Long = 3
Public Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED As Long = 2
Public Const WM_SETTEXT = &HC
Public Const VK_RETURN = &HD
Public Const WM_KEYDOWN = &H100
Public Const WM_KEYUP = &H101

Public Sub OpenLockedPdf() 'Password As String)

    #If VBA7 And Win64 Then
        Dim parentWindow            As LongPtr
        Dim firstChildWindow        As LongPtr
        Dim secondChildFirstWindow  As LongPtr
        Dim secondChildSecondWindow  As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim parentWindow            As Long
        Dim firstChildWindow        As Long
        Dim secondChildFirstWindow  As Long
        Dim secondChildSecondWindow  As Long
    #End If
    Dim timeCount                   As Date
    'Find the handle of the pop-up window.

    Dim Word As New Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As New Word.Document
    Dim Doc_Path As String
    Dim Password As String
    Doc_Path = "Examplepdf.PDF"
    Set WordDoc = Word.Documents.Open(Filename:=Doc_Path, Format:="PDF Files", ConfirmConversions:=False)
    Password = "Password"
    timeCount = Now()
    Do Until Now() > timeCount + TimeValue("00:00:05")
        parentWindow = 0
        DoEvents
        parentWindow = FindWindow("NUIDialog", "Password")
        If parentWindow <> 0 Then Exit Do
    Loop
    If parentWindow <> 0 Then

        'Find the handle of the first child window (it is a group box).
        timeCount = Now()
        Do Until Now() > timeCount + TimeValue("00:00:05")
            firstChildWindow = 0
            DoEvents
            firstChildWindow = FindWindowEx(parentWindow, ByVal 0&, "NetUIHWND", vbNullString)
            If firstChildWindow <> 0 Then Exit Do
        Loop
        If firstChildWindow <> 0 Then
            timeCount = Now()
            Do Until Now() > timeCount + TimeValue("00:00:05")
                secondChildFirstWindow = 0
                DoEvents
                secondChildFirstWindow = FindWindowEx(firstChildWindow, ByVal 0&, "NetUICtrlNotifySink", vbNullString)
                If secondChildFirstWindow <> 0 Then Exit Do
            Loop
            If secondChildFirstWindow <> 0 Then
                timeCount = Now()
                Do Until Now() > timeCount + TimeValue("00:00:05")
                    secondChildSecondWindow = 0
                    DoEvents
                    secondChildSecondWindow = FindWindowEx(secondChildFirstWindow, ByVal 0&, "RICHEDIT60W", vbNullString)
                    If secondChildSecondWindow <> 0 Then Exit Do
                Loop
                If secondChildSecondWindow <> 0 Then
                    'Fill the password in the text box.
                    SendMessage secondChildSecondWindow, WM_SETTEXT, 0&, ByVal Password
                    'Press the OK button (it is the default action, so no need to find the handle of the button).
                    PostMessage secondChildSecondWindow, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0
                    PostMessage secondChildSecondWindow, WM_KEYUP, VK_RETURN, 0
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The Documents.Open command has parameters for writing passwords - have you tried that? Also, **never** use `As New Word.Document` in a declaration; only `As Word.Document`. The former will cause all kinds of problems. You should also not use `As New Word.Application` in a declaration. Use `As Word.Application` then `Set Word = New Word.Application`. That's the way VBA is designed to work; anything else doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @ Cindy Meister. Yes i have tried adding the password to the command parameters but apparently that is for a word doc that is password protected. I am trying to open a PDF that is password protected.

Comment: @ezfrish have You found the solution? I'm really curious, having almost the same problem