# copy password protected pdf to excel via vba

Tags: excel, vba, acrobat

I'm using acrobat reader and the file path of the exe is:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32"

And I have an PDF file, the location of that file:
" C:\Users\caglayan\Desktop\CAGLAYAN\aaa.PDF"

The password of that PDF:
"4pLByo"

How can I copy the whole PDF to excel?

I try to use that but failed:

```vb
Sub pdfexport()

Set MyWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
strPassword = "4pLByo"
Application_Path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32"

PDF_Path = "C:\Users\caglayan\Desktop\CAGLAYAN\\"

Shell_Path = Application_Path & " C:\Users\caglayan\Desktop\CAGLAYAN\aaa\"

Call Shell(pathname:=Shell_Path, windowstyle:=vbNormalFocus)

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")

SendKeys "%vpc"
SendKeys "^a"
SendKeys "^c"

MyWorksheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

''Call Shell("TaskKill /F /IM AcroRd32.exe", vbHide)

End Sub
```

Comment: the first comment to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65173635/18247317) points [here](https://myengineeringworld.net/2018/04/open-password-protected-pdf-vba.html) and it seems the only available source (there is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53949150/18247317) but at a first glance it seems exactly the same code)